# dataframe columnwise comparision to another series

Tags: pandas

It seems dataframe.le doesn't operate column wise fashion.

```
df = DataFrame(randn(8,12))
series=Series(rand(8))
df.le(series)
```

I would expect for each column in `df` it will compare to `series` (so total 12 columns comparison with `series`, so 12 column*8 row comparison involved). But it appears for each element in `df` it will compare against every elements in `series` so this will involves 12(columns)*8(rows) * 8(elements in series) comparison. How can I achieve column by column comparison?
Second question is once I am done with column wise comparison I want to be able to count for each row how many 'true' are there, I am currently doing `astype(int32)` to turn bool into int then do `sum`, does this sound reasonable?

Let me give an example about the first question to show what I meant (using a simpler example since show 8*12 is tough):

```
>>>from pandas import *  
>>>from numpy.random import *  
>>>df = DataFrame(randn(2,5))  
>>>t = DataFrame(randn(2,1))  
>>>df  
          0         1         2         3         4   
0 -0.090283  1.656517 -0.183132  0.904454  0.157861   
1  1.667520 -1.242351  0.379831  0.672118 -0.290858   
>>>t  
          0  
 0  1.291535  
 1  0.151702  
>>>df.le(t)  
       0      1      2      3      4  
0   True  False  False  False  False  
1  False  False  False  False  False
```

What I expect df's column 1 should be:

```
1  
False  
True
```

Because `1.656517 < 1.291535` is `False` and `-1.242351 < 0.151702` is `True`, this is column wise comparison. However the print out is `False False`.

Comment: If I understand the first question right, you do not think that column-by-column comparison is being achieved. But it is: ``df.le(series).shape`` is ``(8, 12)``, not ``(8, 8, 12)``.

Comment: I think it's the index alignment which is causing the problems here, IIUC.  Setting aside indices for a moment, does `df.values <= t.values` give you the array you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the first part of your question, but as to the second part, you can count the `True`s in a boolean DataFrame using [`sum`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
In [11]: df.le(s).sum(axis=0)
Out[11]:
0     4
1     3
2     7
3     3
4     6
5     6
6     7
7     6
8     0
9     0
10    0
11    0
dtype: int64
```

.

Essentially `le` is testing for each column:

```
In [21]: df[0] < s
Out[21]:
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5     True
6     True
7     True
dtype: bool
```

Which for each index is testing:

```
In [22]: df[0].loc[0] < s.loc[0]
Out[22]: False
```